# How to save a windrose plot

Tags: python, plot, save, windrose, rose-plot

I plotted my wind data (direction and speed) with the windrose module https://windrose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html.
The results look nice but I cannot export them as a figure (png, eps, or anything to start with) because the result is a special object type that does not have a 'savefig' attribute, or I don't find it.

I have two pandas.core.series.Series: ff, dd

```
 print(ff)
```

result:

```
TIMESTAMP
2016-08-01 00:00:00    1.643
2016-08-01 01:00:00    2.702
2016-08-01 02:00:00    1.681
2016-08-01 03:00:00    2.208  
....

print(dd)
```

result:

```
TIMESTAMP
2016-08-01 00:00:00    328.80
2016-08-01 01:00:00    299.60
2016-08-01 02:00:00    306.90  
2016-08-01 03:00:00    288.60
...
```

My code looks like:

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes

ax2 = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax2.bar(dd, ff, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white', bins = [0,4,11,17])
ax2.set_legend()
ax2.tick_params(labelsize=18)
ax2.set_legend(loc='center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.05, 0.005), fontsize = 18)
ax2.savefig('./figures/windrose.eps')
ax2.savefig('./figures/windrose.png')
```

But the result is:

```
AttributeError: 'WindroseAxes' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

Do you know how to create a figure out of the result so I can use it in my work?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pyplot.savefig()` from `matplotlib`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import Image

df_ws = pd.read_csv('WindData.csv')
# df_ws has `Wind Direction` and `Wind Speed`

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(df_ws['Wind Direction'], df_ws['Wind Speed'])
ax.set_legend()

# savefig() supports eps, jpeg, jpg, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rgba, svg, svgz, tif, tiff
plt.savefig('WindRose.jpg')
plt.close()

Image(filename='WindRose.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are using box type of windrose module. Then the following code converts your wind rose into an image:

```
ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.box(direction=wd, var=ws, bins=bins)
buff = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buff, format="jpeg")
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
pixmap.loadFromData(buff.getvalue())
dialog.ui.windrose_label.setScaledContents(True)
dialog.ui.windrose_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is occuring because you are trying to save the subplot instead of the figure. Try:

```
 fig,ax2 = plt.subplots(1,1) # Or whatever you need.
 # The windrose code you showed
 fig.savefig('./figures/windrose.png')
```

Comment: Yes, this is a start. But now I get the windrose plot overlayed over a square empty figure... my code is the same, only added the line: fig,ax2 = plt.subplots(1,1) and changed the line: ax2 = WindroseAxes.from_ax() to ax2 = WindroseAxes.from_ax(fig=fig).. I also tried ax2 = WindroseAxes.from_ax(ax = ax2) instead but then I get an AttributeError: Unknown property normed... 
if I delete the 'normed' attribute from ax2.bar(..) I get AttributeError: Unknown property opening...